# Deserializing JSON with odd structure with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize some JSON into an object using JSON.NET's JsonConvert class.

Code I'm using with a JSON structure sample:

```
var desObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Market>("{\"success\":\"1\",\"return\":
{\"sellorders\":
[{\"sellprice\":\"0.00001099\",\"quantity\":\"60.00000000\",\"total\":\"0.00065940\"},
{\"sellprice\":\"0.00001100\",\"quantity\":\"1000.00000000\",\"total\":\"0.01100000\"},
{\"sellprice\":\"0.00001105\",\"quantity\":\"60.00000000\",\"total\":\"0.01200\"}]}}");
```

And my market class:

```
class Market
    {
        [JsonProperty("success")]
        public int Success { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sellorders")]
        public List<SellOrder> SellOrders {get; set;}

        [JsonProperty("buyorders")]
        public List<BuyOrder> BuyOrders {get; set;}
    }

    public class SellOrder
    {
        [JsonProperty("sellprice")]
        public decimal SellPrice { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("quantity")]
        public decimal Quantity { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("total")]
        public decimal Total { get; set; }
    }

    public class BuyOrder
    {
        [JsonProperty("buyprice")]
        public decimal BuyPrice { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("quantity")]
        public decimal Quantity { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("total")]
        public decimal Total { get; set; }
    }
```

The thing that's causing me problems is the fact that the data is under the 'return' key. If I remove the return key, this works perfectly. How would I go about getting my market object to behave like this:

```
foreach(SellOrder sellorder in desObj.SellOrders)
{
    Console.WriteLine(sellorder.total.ToString());
}
```

I've tried experimenting with making the return attribute a dynamic list, then retrieving the sell/buy-orders that way, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: My current work-around is to modify the original JSON as follows: result = result.Replace("return\":{\"", "");
            result = result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1); ...this works, but it's definitely a hack. I'd prefer a cleaner solution if there is one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you do something like that?

```
class Market
    {
      [JsonProperty("success")]
      public int Success { get; set; }
      [JsonProperty("return")]
      public Container Container { get; set; }

    }
    class Container
    {
      [JsonProperty("sellorders")]
      public List<SellOrder> SellOrders { get; set; }

      [JsonProperty("buyorders")]
      public List<BuyOrder> BuyOrders { get; set; }
    }

    public class SellOrder
    {
      [JsonProperty("sellprice")]
      public decimal SellPrice { get; set; }

      [JsonProperty("quantity")]
      public decimal Quantity { get; set; }

      [JsonProperty("total")]
      public decimal Total { get; set; }
    }

    public class BuyOrder
    {
      [JsonProperty("buyprice")]
      public decimal BuyPrice { get; set; }

      [JsonProperty("quantity")]
      public decimal Quantity { get; set; }

      [JsonProperty("total")]
      public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

and then access you data like that:

```
foreach(SellOrder sellorder in desObj.Container.SellOrders)
{
    Console.WriteLine(sellorder.total.ToString());
}
```

Comment: This worked - thanks. Would be nice if there was a clever solution using the JsonProperty Annotation, since the entire API I'm working with does this on every request. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to skip the return property in Json using attributes :-(